# Drupal 7: Search multiple search types at the same time

Tags: search, drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've built a calendar system for our website, and made it searchable using the hook_search_info and hook_search_execute. The problem is, I'd like when users use the search box at the top of our site to see results that match content and events on the calendar. Right now it only shows content results because the form gets submitted the 'search/node'. Is there a way to make drupal show results across all search types? My hook_search_info registers my module so that it uses the 'search/tcmi-calendar' path.

Answer (score 0):

before 2 days only, Im needed something like you want .. and the problem was solved for me, when i using a [Multi indexing search api](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_multi), Im using its and all work fine ..

to can use it you need to install a

[Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api)

Search views (enable it after install search api)

[Database search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db)

after you install these go to admin/config/search/search_api, and Add server, 
after you add server, you can now add indexs you want .. 
then go to view, add new view .. select multi indexes from show list ..
and config your field as you want ...